# retainAll not printing the values

Tags: java

hi i am trying to get common values from two string lists... List A has a values obtained by querying the Excel database and List B has a values obtained by querying the SQL database. i want to have common values from A and B. for that i used retainAll collection. but it is not printing the common values.instead its giving me [ ]. please help me to solve this problem. how to get common values otherthan using retainAll. please correct my code snippet.

```
      //connecting excel database and storing its values
      Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
      conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:spreadsheetdb","","");
      out.println("Excel Database connected" +"<br>");

      Statement stmt=conn.createStatement();
      String excelquery="Select * from [Sheet1$]";
      ResultSet excelvalues= stmt.executeQuery(excelquery);

      List A= new  ArrayList();
      while(excelvalues.next()){
            A.add(excelvalues.getString("name"));}

   //connection sql Db and storing its values

   Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
   connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:copyknowledgebase","sa","sqladmin");
   out.println("<br>"+"MSSQL connected " +"<br>")

   Statement statement=connection.createStatement();
   String conceptquery="Select * from dbo.conc";
   ResultSet conceptdetails=statement.executeQuery(conceptquery);
   Timestamp ts = new Timestamp(new java.util.Date().getTime());

  List B = new  ArrayList();
  while(conceptdetails.next()){
  B.add(conceptdetails.getString("Cname"));
  }
  B.retainAll (A);
  out.println(B);
```

Comment: Are you sure your lists have the data you expect before you call retainAll. What happens if you print out their values before hand.

Comment: yes i have common elements from both list.

Comment: I am not shure if retainAll is good for finding common elements of collection. For example if list A={a,b,b,c} and B={a,a,b,d} A.retainAll(B) = {a,b,b} but B has only one 'b' inside. RetainAll just removes elements that are not in other collection.

Answer (score 0):

This strongly suggests that there are no common values in your lists `A` and `B`. Have you tried debugging / single-stepping through to check?

`retainAll(collection)` should do what you expect of it. Consider the following simple example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws DataException {
  List<Integer> all = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8));
  List<Integer> even = Arrays.asList(2,4,6,8);
  all.retainAll(even);
  System.out.println(all);
}
```

...which prints [2, 4, 6, 8] - i.e. the common values.

As regards altenatives, there are lots of ways you could do this - here's one example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws DataException {
  List<Integer> all = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8));
  List<Integer> even = Arrays.asList(2,4,6,8);

  List<Integer> common = new ArrayList<Integer>(all);
  for (Integer i : all){
    if (!even.contains(i)){
      common.remove(i);
    }
  }
  System.out.println(common);
}
```

...which again prints [2, 4, 6, 8]

(Actually, that's very similar to the way that `AbstractCollection` does `retainAll()`, except that it uses an `Iterator` rather than a `for each` loop and it can therefore modify the collection as it goes, rather than having to create a copy.)